# Build a list of the names of students currently enrolled in a number of units strictly greater than the unitThreshold

Tags: java

SO i have a lab thats fairly simple but i believe that my brain is just fried now lol and i have it due in an hour... I would love any help that can be offered ... The purpose of this is to build a list using the map function i believe
...

The following is a class i made for the map class to use

```
  /*
 * This file should remain unchanged from what i understand
 */
class Course
{
   private final String name;
   private final int numUnits;

   public Course(final String name, final int numUnits)
   {
      this.name = name;
      this.numUnits = numUnits;
   }

   public String getName()
   {
      return name;
   }

   public int getNumUnits()
   {
      return numUnits;
   }
}
```

But now I have the following map class that I am stuck on .. I have done the proper imports but im so lost when it comes to this map function

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

class ExampleMap
{
   public static List<String> highEnrollmentStudents(
      Map<String, List<Course>> courseListsByStudentName, int unitThreshold)
   {
      List<String> overEnrolledStudents = new LinkedList<>();

      /*
         Build a list of the names of students currently enrolled
         in a number of units strictly greater than the unitThreshold.
      */

      return overEnrolledStudents;      
   }
}
```

Here is a test case i was given in case this may help

```
 @Test
   public void testExampleMap1()
   {
      List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("Julie", "Zoe");
      Map<String, List<Course>> courseListsByStudent = new HashMap<>();

      courseListsByStudent.put("Julie",
         Arrays.asList(
            new Course("CPE 123", 4),
            new Course("CPE 101", 4),
            new Course("CPE 202", 4),
            new Course("CPE 203", 4),
            new Course("CPE 225", 4)));
      courseListsByStudent.put("Paul",
         Arrays.asList(
            new Course("CPE 101", 4),
            new Course("CPE 202", 4),
            new Course("CPE 203", 4),
            new Course("CPE 225", 4)));
      courseListsByStudent.put("Zoe",
         Arrays.asList(
            new Course("CPE 123", 4),
            new Course("CPE 203", 4),
            new Course("CPE 471", 4),
            new Course("CPE 473", 4),
            new Course("CPE 476", 4),
            new Course("CPE 572", 4)));

      /*
       * Why compare HashSets here?  Just so that the order of the
       * elements in the list is not important for this test.
       */
      assertEquals(new HashSet<>(expected),
         new HashSet<>(ExampleMap.highEnrollmentStudents(
            courseListsByStudent, 16)));
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're supposed to get a list of students who are enrolled in >= `unitThreshold` number of units? If so, this should help:

```
 for (String studentName : courseListsByStudentName.keySet()) {
     int units = 0;
     List<Course> courses = courseListsByStudentName.get(studentName);
     for (Course course : courses) {
         units += course.getNumUnits();
     }
     if (units > unitThreshold) {
         overEnrolledStudents.add(studentName);
     }
 }
```

Comment: im sorry but what comes after .filter(studentName ? im asking about the '->'.

Comment: Sorry, look at my new code. I made it more understandable and fixed it.

Comment: ExampleMap.java:21: error: variable units might not have been initialized
         units += course.getNumUnits();
         ^
ExampleMap.java:23: error: variable units might not have been initialized
     if (units > unitThreshold) {

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: You're welcome and good luck! (also don't forget to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work))